# Is it possible to remove but not delete an image from Channel Images?

Tags: channel-images

Is there a way to remove images from an entry but not delete it from the filesystem?

Thank you in advance.

L.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to remove an image without deleting it. But you could set up categories in a custom field and make one of the categories "closed" and then filter out images with category=closed.